# Yii simple master-detail CGridView solution?

Tags: gridview, grid, widget, components, yii

I have something like order-order_details
 - so when I pick in a row I want to show beneath it the details (as another grid)

And being able to add from there the details as well and edit them (probably in dialogs)

Is there any simple solution? component.. either for master detail or for dialog edit, delete, add ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eupdatedialog/